# Array of UITableViews

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to create a Slack-like app where a user can create channels and where each channel contains different chats. I started by creating a single array of chats and used Parse to save and load those. Now that I have the base, I am trying to create the channels. I am having trouble because it would seem like I could just create 2 classes (1 for the chats, 1 for the channels) and have channels be an array of chats (which is an array of strings). However, when I try to create the array of chats, I get an error saying

> Instance member 'chats' cannot be used on type 'ChannelsTVC'

**MOBChatTVC class**

```
class MOBChatTVC: UITableViewController {

    var chatArray = [String]() {
        didSet {
            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

**ChannelsTVC class**

```
class ChannelsTVC: UITableViewController {

    var chats = MOBChatTVC().chatArray
    var channels = [chats]() {
        didSet {
            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

#### EDIT

I was helped with the error. Now...my new question...

How do I create an array of chatArrays?

Comment: `chats` is a variable. An array declaration requires a type. Therefore `[chats]` just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurs because compiler expects that you pass the Object type instead rather than variable itself e.g

```
var channels = [String]()  {
    didSet {

        tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Also Something Wrong with your Design: You making a new instance of  `MOBChatTVC` inside  `ChannelsTVC` to access the property `chatArray` since MOBChatTVC extends `UITableViewController` its purpose inside `MOBChatTVC` is more unclear. Either way, you may want to make a new instance of ChannelsTVC and access to its properties and methods as follows

```
     class ChannelsTVC: UITableViewController {            

       var channels = [String]() {
       didSet {
        tableView?.reloadData()
       }
      } // channels

      var myMobChatTVC = MOBChatTVC()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      channels = myMobChatTVC.chatArray

     } // viewDidLoad
  } // ChannelsTVC
```